# WP_User_Query get users registered between two dates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can we get users registered between two dates?

My code is

```
$user_args['meta_query'][0] = array(
                                'key'     => 'user_registered',
                                'value'   => '2015-07-05 00:00:00',
                                'type'    => 'DATETIME',
                                'compare' => '>='
                            );

$user_args['meta_query'][1] = array(
                                    'key'     => 'user_registered',
                                    'value'   => '2015-07-06 23:59:59',
                                    'type'    => 'DATETIME',
                                    'compare' => '<='
                                );

$user_query = new WP_User_Query($user_args);
```

But no result.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but;

```html
$start ='2015-07-05';
$end   ='2015-07-06'; 


$start = new DateTime($start. ' 00:00:00');
$end   = new DateTime($end. ' 23:59:59');

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT wp_users.* FROM wp_users WHERE 1=1 AND CAST(user_registered AS DATE) BETWEEN %s AND %s ORDER BY user_login ASC",$start,$end);
 
     $users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
 
     return $users;
```

Answer (score 0):

user_registered is not a meta field, it's part of the users table.  You will need to use a date query which is answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174707/108581